How to keep the file upload process running in the background of the app in Android Studio?
How to keep the file upload process running in the background of the app? Android Studio, Java.
I was able to successfully upload the file but after exiting the app the upload process stopped.
I want the upload process to not stop even if the user exits the app.

You can use the foreground service to implement such functionality. Foreground service is made for the purpose like this. You can provide the upload percent as well to let user know the acknowledgement and once the file upload done you can stop the service.

You can use WorkManager to manage background tasks of your app. See documentation: https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/persistent/getting-started#define_the_work
Or you can use Foreground service (with notification) to keep your task alive while uploading: https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/foreground-services
